# Right plugin version in package.json but not in plugin.xml

Tags: cordova, plugins, cordova-plugins, package.json

I create a cordova app. I added a plugin.
The plugin version is ok in my package.json files both under the cordova folder and the plugin folder, but in my plugin.xml under the plugin folder it's an older version.

How can that be possible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean config.xml ?

Comment: No, plugin.xml cause I use Cordova 9.